# How do I make the game scene fill the safe space in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

[A picture of the simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA1FJ.png)

I linked a picture of the simulation above. I haven't change a single thing about the project when I created a new SpriteKit game project. The only thing I did was run it on the iPhone 11 Pro, but I think the constraints of the GameScene usually are supposed to fill the screen.

As you can see, the grey area is the game scene, but I can't seem to make it any bigger to fill each iPhone.

How do I make the game scene fill the safe area? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you could show some of your code of your attempt then others can help. Otherwise there are no enough information to give you a suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882860/skview-does-not-cover-the-entire-screen-area/64887828#64887828

Comment: After you have completed the step in the link above. You have to set your scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill or .fill in GameViewController